# Get top 1 from distinct attribute on CoreData

Tags: ios, iphone, core-data, ios8, ios9

Hi I have a table with the format shown below.

I want to build an history view, so I need the last messages from distinct users, ordered by timestamp!

`+---+-------------------+-------------------+---------------+
|   |     Username      |      Message      |    Timestamp  |
+---+-------------------+-------------------+---------------+
| 1 | John              |       Hello       | 486380161.723 |
| 2 | Mark              |    Spreadsheet    | 486380264.723 |
| 3 | John              |        FYI        | 486380366.723 |
| 4 | John              |        Bye        | 486557497.271 |
| 5 | Mark              |    How are you?   | 486557597.274 |
| 6 | Mario             |       What?       | 486558597.274 |
+---+-------------------+-------------------+---------------+`

This is what my result should be.

`+---+-------------------+-------------------+---------------+
|   |     Username      |      Message      |    Timestamp  |
+---+-------------------+-------------------+---------------+
| 6 | Mario             |       What?       | 486558597.274 |
| 5 | Mark              |    How are you?   | 486557597.274 |
| 4 | John              |        Bye        | 486557497.271 |
+---+-------------------+-------------------+---------------+`

For now, I'm getting all distinct `username`, iterating each one and querying the messages for that username, ordered by timestamp, with `limit(1)`.

I'm not happy with this solution so anyone can help me on a better one?

Thanks,
Mário

Comment: CoreData isn't a relational database. It is an object persistence system. Perhaps you should store your messages in SQLite ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible to do it in two fetches, with one caveat that I'll mention when I get to it.

The first fetch gets the usernames and the most recent timestamp for each:

```
    let maxTimestampRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Entity")
    maxTimestampRequest.resultType = .DictionaryResultType

    let maxTimestampExpression = NSExpression(format: "max:(timestamp)")
    let maxTimestampExpressiondescription = NSExpressionDescription()
    maxTimestampExpressiondescription.name = "maxTimestamp"
    maxTimestampExpressiondescription.expression = maxTimestampExpression
    maxTimestampExpressiondescription.expressionResultType = .DoubleAttributeType

    maxTimestampRequest.propertiesToFetch = ["username", maxTimestampExpressiondescription]
    maxTimestampRequest.propertiesToGroupBy = ["username"]
```

Execute that fetch and you get an array of dictionaries. Each dictionary contains a username and the most recent timestamp for that username:

```
Optional([{
    maxTimestamp = "486557497.271";
    username = John;
}, {
    maxTimestamp = "486558597.274";
    username = Mario;
}, {
    maxTimestamp = "486557597.274";
    username = Mark;
}])
```

Getting the complete records requires a second fetch. If the results of the previous fetch are in an array called `results`,

```
    var predicates = [NSPredicate]()
    for maxTimestampInfo in results! {
        let username = maxTimestampInfo["username"]!
        let timestamp = maxTimestampInfo["maxTimestamp"]!
        let partialPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "username=%@ and timestamp=%@", argumentArray:[ username, timestamp ])
        predicates.append(partialPredicate)
    }
    let completePredicate = NSCompoundPredicate(orPredicateWithSubpredicates: predicates)

    let fetch = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Entity")
    fetch.predicate = completePredicate
```

Execute **that** fetch and you get the full managed objects that match your requirements.

The caveat is that the predicate in the second fetch could potentially be very large, depending on the number of users you have.

Comment: Thank you @Tom. The solution works perfectly. I'll edit your answer later with Objc version alright?